# How can Thread Environment Blocks reside above the address space limit?

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64, portable-executable, wow64

I recently noticed that the 32-bit version of Cheat Engine has its Thread Environment Block at a higher address than what is available to the 32-bit address space. To my knowledge user space is only accessible up to address 0x7FFFFFFF, but this TEB was located at 0xFFFDB000. Every TEB I ever saw started at 0x7EFD8000 or 0x7EFDB000 and subsequent TEBs continued downwards. I assume since Cheat Engine is a memory scanner it is to simplify the scanning process. The Process Environment Block had also been moved. Can anyone please tell me how this is possible? Is this a setting in the Portable Executable, by any chance?

Comment: in wow64 process `FFFDB000` is possible and correct address

Comment: @RbMm It is indeed a WOW64 process. I've never ever seen this happen to any other TEB, though. They always seem to start at 0x7EFD8000 or 0x7EFDB000. What makes this program so special, you think?

Comment: @RbMm I'm using Win7 x64.

Comment: really for 32 bit space available all addresses from 0 to `0xffffffff` simply for x86 windows from `0x80000000` begin kernel space, while in x64 windows(wow64 processes) - all this space - is user mode process space. and teb can be at any page aligned address

Comment: i look on win7 - this is usual sitiation for wow64 processes - where teb and peb placed. so nothing special in your process. nobody move teb or ped. system allocate it at this address

Comment: @RbMm I'm with you. I just find it very peculiar that this program always has its TEB at this exact address (0xFFFDB000), yet if I run another program which has a larger memory footprint it still gets the TEB at 0x7EFD8000. My guess is that the program somehow asks for the system allocations to be moved further up.

Comment: this is feature of win7. not only related to this program

Comment: @RbMm Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Don't you find it suspicious it always happens to the same program but no other programs?

Comment: i just look on win7 x64 wow64 process - here also teb at `FFFDB000` address. nothing suspicious

Comment: @RbMm Did you try a random program or Cheat Engine?

Comment: i try random program

Comment: @RbMm Crap. Windows strikes again. Thanks.

Comment: this is for files which have flag `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Characteristics`

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, it was exactly something like this I was looking for. Just to be sure, then this must mean both Cheat Engine and the program you tried used this PE characteristic, yes?

Comment: yes. programs without this flag limited to 0x80000000

Comment: @RbMm Please write an answer so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 32 bit programs available addresses from `0x00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF` but on x86 platform historical `[0x00000000, 0x7FFFFFFF]` was user space and `[0x80000000, 0xFFFFFFFF]` kernel space. but on x64, where 32bit apps run in wow64 subsystem this already not true - all 32bit range - `[0x80000000, 0xFFFFFFFF]` is user space. but for compatible reason system anyway restrict user address space of wow64 bit apps to 2GB `[0x00000000, 0x7FFFFFFF]` by default. for break this and have 4GB space need use flag

**`IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`** *The application can handle addresses larger than 2 GB.* in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Characteristics`

[On 64-bit editions of Windows, 32-bit applications marked with the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag have 4 GB of address space available.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473(VS.85).aspx)